# Como usar 2 idiomas en reconocimiento de voz en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa para detectar el idioma que hablas mediante un micrófono en python, pero quisiera usar dos idiomas, por ejemplo el español y francés.

Mi codigo:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Comienza a hablar....")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio,language="es-ES, fr-FR")
        print("Palabra: {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("No se reconoció la palabra")
```

En el código coloque las iniciales de es-ES y fr-FR, pero no funciona cuando intento hablar en francés, es posible tener dos lenguajes?

Comment: En una búsqueda rápida no encontré una respuesta satisfactoria. Yo que tú haría dos consultas, cada lenguaje por separado pidiendo una lista de resultados y comparo la probabilidad del mejor acierto para entregar solo una respuesta (la que tenga el porcentaje más alto).

Comment: @SergioR y como obtendria el porcentaje de acierto?

Comment: `recognize_google(audio, language='es-ES',show_all=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente en una consulta no puedes preguntar por dos idiomas. La opción es realizar dos consultas, utilizar `show_all=True` para ver el porcentaje de acierto de la mejor alternativa y compararlas para determinar el idioma.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def transcripcion(audio,lang,prob):
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio,language=lang,show_all=True)
        if len(text)!=0:
            print(f"Palabra: {text['alternative'][0]['transcript']}")
            prob[lang]=text['alternative'][0]['confidence']
        else:
            print(f"No se reconoció la palabra en {lang}")
    except:
        print(f"Ocurrió un problema usando el idioma {lang}")

r = sr.Recognizer()
langs=["es-ES","fr-FR"]
probabilidad={}

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Comienza a hablar....")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    for lang in langs:
        probabilidad[lang]=0
        transcripcion(audio,lang,probabilidad)

ordenados={k: v for k, v in sorted(probabilidad.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
for leng in ordenados:
    print(f"La probabilidad de que sea {leng} es de {ordenados[leng]}")
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono!